# Use of undefined constant and mysqli_connect():

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know why I'm getting this error. I'm just following what tutorial say.
How do I fix this?

```
<?php

define ("HOST_NAME", "localhost");
define ("HOST_USER", "root");
define ("HOST_PASSWORD", "");
define ("DB_NAME", "db_user");
?>
```

And actual code

```
<?php 
require_once("config.php");

class MySQLDatabase{

private $connection;

function __construct(){
    $this->open_connection();
}

public function open_connection(){
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(HOST_NAME,HOST_USER,HOST_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
      die("Database connection failed" .
           mysqli_connect_error() .   
             " ( " . mysqli_connect_errno . ")"
      );
    }

}
```

Errors

> Notice: Use of undefined constant HOST_NAME - assumed 'HOST_NAME' in C:\xampp\htdocs\first-project\includes\database.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant HOST_USER - assumed 'HOST_USER' in C:\xampp\htdocs\first-project\includes\database.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant HOST_PASSWORD - assumed 'HOST_PASSWORD' in C:\xampp\htdocs\first-project\includes\database.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_NAME - assumed 'DB_NAME' in C:\xampp\htdocs\first-project\includes\database.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\first-project\includes\database.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\first-project\includes\database.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant mysqli_connect_errno - assumed 'mysqli_connect_errno' in C:\xampp\htdocs\first-project\includes\database.php on line 17
> Database connection failedphp_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. ( mysqli_connect_errno)

Comment: does first code-block is `config.php` ? and where this file is located?

Comment: depends on what your origin file is in accessing it. I don't see where you're using that class.

Comment: Do you have multiple config.php files in different directories? Maybe you're not including the one you think you are.

Comment: if you're not `require`ing the file where you are `define`ing those constants in `config.php`, you can't use them. Try moving the `define` statements into database.php and if that fixes the error, make sure you include the defines correctly.

Comment: @mike but i only have 1 config file

Comment: Error reporting states `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION)...` being caused by the missing brace as P. Leger stated in his answer. You accepted the wrong one, in my view. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred -ii- really dont see somthing about syntax errors in author message... just not full code provided

Comment: @M0rtiis Please don't argue; it's a parse error. Do you think I didn't test this?

Comment: @Fred nope.. we see all of errors he recieves. nothing about syntax. not all of his code he posted

Comment: @M0rtiis open your code editor and put their class code in there, then come back and tell me different. Count the braces and match them.

Comment: i see it without copying his code to my editor. also i see Notices and Warnings he recieves. you too? i dont see there any syntax errors. you too? what does it mean? he forgot to copy last line of his code. Syntax error is certainly not a SUBJECT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89631/discussion-between-m0rtiis-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution (far from best) will be to replace

```
require_once("config.php");
```

with

```
define ("HOST_NAME", "localhost");
define ("HOST_USER", "root");
define ("HOST_PASSWORD", "");
define ("DB_NAME", "db_user");
```

and forget about `config.php`

this will not break you app-logic in other places, i believe noone except `MySQLDatabase` class needs them

Comment: This is a band-aid if anything.

Comment: mb. but your dupe-mark is really "nothing" about subject

Comment: Tell you what; you use the code that OP posted character for character, set error reporting to catch and display, and you'll change your mind; guaranteed ;-)

Comment: this is the best so far.

Comment: @M0rtiis what if i call database.php to function.php it is safe?

Comment: what is function.php ?

Comment: all of my logic to my program is stored there

Comment: sorry for asking a noob question because im newbie at using php

Comment: safe - i think yes. but no need to do that

Comment: what do you mean no need to do that? sry i cant chat to chat room i need 20 rep haha.

Comment: what do you mean "call database.php to function.php"? call one file to another? not very clear

Comment: example
'
 include_once("/include/database.php"/
class UserAcces
function login{
*insert code here
}'
like that.

Comment: @M0rtiis Thankyou so much dude can you give me advice or some good tutorial? :D i really want to learn this

Comment: with pleasure but "my" beginner-tutorials were in russian and with php3 :) i dont know good sources for "start level"

Comment: see somthing here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Comment: Thankyou again! haha next time i ask you again if i have a question or a error :D